# When was the pact revealed in The Crimes of Grindelwald made?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

In *Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald* we found out that Grindelwald and Dumbledore

> made a blood pact so they cannot fight each other. The memory Albus saw in the mirror implies that they did it out of friendship.

But it seems to me, that there is no time when this could have been made. In the time of the movie Ariana Dumbledore is already dead (Albus said that to Leta in the Hogwarts).

We know that Ariana died in a fight between Grindelwald, Dumbledore and Aberforth as described by Aberforth, i.e. on [Pottermore site about Ariana](https://www.pottermore.com/features/the-mysterious-life-and-death-of-ariana-dumbledore):

> I pulled out my wand, and he pulled out his, and I had the Cruciatus Curse used on me by my brother’s best friend – and Albus was trying to stop him, and then all three of us were duelling

So at that time

> the blood pact couldn't be already effective. They obviously could fight each other.

But on the other hand, it would be strange if

> they would make this pact after Ariana's dead, they weren't friends anymore after this event.

So, the question is obvious:

**When was the pact between Grindelwald and Dumbledore made?**

Comment: The pact must have been made before the duel but it couldn't have been long beforehand.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot If it would be before the duel, they wouldn't be able to duel each other.

Comment: There’s no explicit details on what actually happened during the duel. For all we know they didn’t actually duel each other. Or some spells were “allowed”. Or the act of casting a spell against one another made it rebound and hit Ariana. At the moment all we have is speculation.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot We now they were dualling, it is even part of the question as a citation from Pottermore: "all three of us were duelling". Maybe something was allowed, but it wouldn't make sense to have such pact with allowing spells that can kill a person.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as per the Future Works Policy as this will certainly be addressed in the upcoming films.